# Python change function input name internaly

Tags: python

I need to create a function which can:

1. Inspect input arguments and get the number of inputs and their values
2. Create a loop, and add string '_in' after each input name
3. Make the new inputs global
4. Assign new inputs with old values

I tried to use inspect.getargspec() but it seems like this should be called outside the function. So any suggestions?

Here is the pseudo code:
Define this function:

```
def set_global(a1, a2, a3, .... an):
    #the number of arguments is not fixed and we need to detect that
    for old_input in total input:
         new_input_name=str(old_input.name)+'_in'
         global new_input_name 
         new_input_name = old_input.value
```

Comment: What's your use case? You may want to use a decorator here.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: I have updated my post with a broken function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you're looking for the `globals` function.

```
a = 1
globals()['a'] = 2
print a  #2
globals()['a_in'] = 2
print a_in  #2
```

You could put this in a function:

```
def do_something_with_globals(**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        globals()[k+'_in'] = v
```

Which could be called like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
do_something_with_globals(a=a,b=b)
print a_in
print b_in
```

But, honestly, I really don't think this is a good idea...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, this is part of the functions for a unittest. I failed to send external parameters to the unittest. The only solution I came up is to use global variables...

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print "number of fixed args: %d" % len(args)
    print "number of keyword args: %d" % len(kwargs)
    print "keyword argument names: %s" % str(kwargs.keys())
```

We can apply this with `globals()` to do what you want:

```
def set_globals(**kwargs):
    for argname in kwargs:
        globals()['%s_in' % argname] = kwargs[argname]
```

So, using the above function from the Python interactive interpreter:

```
>>> set_globals(foo='x', bar='y')
>>> foo_in
'x'
>>> bar_in
'y'
```

Comment: Is there a sane way to create local variables dynamically in *any language*?

Comment: @mgilson Funny, funny. What I mean is that the Python standard explicitly disallows all practices which result in dynamic local variable creation. Contrast this to, for example, Perl's `$$`.

Comment: Actually, At the module level, you can modify the dict returned by `globals`.  In many implementations (I think) you can do the same thing with `locals`, but that one isn't guaranteed.  As far as contrasting it with `perl`, then I would need to learn perl to understand that syntax -- (I think I get it) -- but I'd rather not learn perl ...

Comment: @mgilson Using `locals` that way is unsafe. Which is why I used the word "sane".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the post, which might explain the question a little bit...

Comment: Anyway, I think we can both agree that this sort of power should probably not be used even when available.  If you really wanted to, you could probably use `exec` for this rather than `locals` (which happily doesn't seem to work as I expected) ...

Comment: @tao.hong I've updated my answer to match your clarified question.